# Converting an RGB image to CMYK in WPF

Tags: wpf, rgb, cmyk

How to convert image from one color model to another ?                                                                                                 Can you show me some code snippets ? I have used google but i have not found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to a class that will allow you to do pretty much everything with images in wpf.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i understand how to program the algorithm but i don't understand how to convert image

Comment: Ah I see now you are asking for an IMAGE and not a color. I changed my answer. Check it out.